# Executing functions after multiple data sources have been loaded in Leaflet AJAX

Tags: leaflet, geojson, ajax

I have a leaflet map that takes in data from multiple sources via the LeafLet Ajax plugin.

I want to execute certain functions only after ALL the data has been loaded, not just one layer.

The data loading part of my code is fairly simple and looks like this:

```
data_layer1=L.geoJSON.ajax(data1.geojson,{options});
data_layer2=L.geoJSON.ajax(data2.geojson,{options});
data_layer3=L.geoJSON.ajax(data3.geojson,{options});
```

Now if I want to execute a function after data_layer1 is loaded, I will have to

```
data_layer1.on("data:loaded",function(){
      //function body
});
```

But what I want to do is execute a function after data_layer1, data_layer2, and data_layer3 is loaded. How would I do that?

I am fairly new to AJAX, so the Asynchronous part of this is a bit disorientating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to use `setTimeout` function to check when all three layers are loaded, something like this:

```
var layer1Loaded = false;
var layer2Loaded = false;
var layer3Loaded = false;

function checkAllLoaded() {
  if (layer1Loaded && layer2Loaded && layer3Loaded) {
    // process loaded layers
    }
  else {
    setTimeout(checkAllLoaded, 100);
  }
}

data_layer1.on("data:loaded",function(){
  layer1Loaded = true;
});
data_layer2.on("data:loaded",function(){
  layer2Loaded = true;
});
data_layer3.on("data:loaded",function(){
  layer3Loaded = true;
});

checkAllLoaded();
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs there is a function `L.Util.ajax` that returns a promise. So this should work (is untested)

```js
data_layer1=L.Util.ajax(data1.geojson,{options});
data_layer2=L.Util.ajax(data2.geojson,{options});
data_layer3=L.Util.ajax(data3.geojson,{options});

Promise.all([data_layer1, data_layer2, data_layer3]).then(loadedLayers => {
    // The variable loadedLayers is an array with the three loaded layers
})
```

Edit: The above code assumes a modern browser. Since IE don't support Promise a polyfill have to be added to make it work in IE

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

And if the arrow-syntax isn't supported it should be replaced with old-school function syntax

```js
Promise.all([data_layer1, data_layer2, data_layer3]).then(function(loadedLayers) {
    // The variable loadedLayers is an array with the three loaded layers
})
```

Comment: `Promise` is not supported in any version of Internet Explorer.

Comment: That is a good point. In case IE-support is important you would need to use a Promise polyfill. You can do that by adding `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>` in the head of your document

Comment: You should include this in your answer. There is also question of `=>` syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Stackoverflow. I have tried to clarify my answer